# How to concatenate the string before the column name in select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In my application, retrieving the column names of the table using a SQL query. Before the column name I want to concatenate the string before the column name, then all column names must concatenate the string, how to concatenate the string before the column name in SQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have **no clue** what you're really asking..... can you show **some code samples** of what you're trying to do and explain where you're stuck??

Comment: show your `retrieving the column names of the table using a SQL query` query

Comment: Please ask in different way or show some sample code to understand, what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you trying to get the table name to appear before the columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a

```
select somecolumn from sometable
```

you can have that "string before" by doing

```
select somecolumn as [somestringbeforesomecolumn] 
    from sometable
```

See the following reference [Sql Alias at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.getConcatValues
(
    @table_name NVARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + c.name
        FROM sys.columns c
        WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

    RETURN @SQL

END
GO

SELECT dbo.function_name('dbo.table1')
```